# How can I undo adding a PPA and installing packages from it?

Tags: package-management, ppa, cinnamon

I was following a guide and did this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable   
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install cinnamon nemo
```

Now I am having a lot of trouble due to this. How can I undo these actions?

Comment: I think some more information is necessary in order to properly help you. Is Cinnamon your only desktop environment? What version of ubuntu are you using? What exactly is your trouble? Can you give us the link to the guide? What exactly were you trying to do? Because if for example you just `remove` or `purge` the installed content it could break your desktop environment leaving you only with a console.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Takkat.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get purge cinnamon nemo
```

Then restart.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` should be enough.

Comment: How do you figure that c_korn?

Comment: I think to be on the safe side it's usefull to do `sudo apt-get update -f` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` after your last command. That way any packages that are dependencies for other parts of your system that might have been uninstalled by accident by the previous commands will be reinstalled. (Might not be applicable in your situation, just for future readers)